# lyx: Have a home tour file from early 2000's created in Windows and cannot open in my MAC OS

Tags: lyx, mac

I have an old LYX file on disc that was created for me in the early 2000s (Windows).  It contains photos I really need. When I try to open it it says it cannot find the app.  I used to be able to watch it like a home tour and now cannot.  On top of it all, I use a MAC OS.

How do I convert just to capture some photos from it?  I hate to install an app if I don't have to.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have the PDF file? Maybe you can extract the picture from the PDF file.

Comment: I do not understand why installing the software (and de-installing it 10 min later) is a problem? The process of writing the question here seems to be more work :). https://www.lyx.org/Download

Comment: What does **"home tour"** mean in the title of your question?

Comment: Unless your file happens to be a LyX archive file (I'm guessing this feature did not even exist back then), I don't think your .lyx file has embedded photos. In any case, .lyx files are text files so you can open it with a text editor and should be able to get an idea of what it has.